# Check if JValue string has a value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm performing an ng-if on my li element, to check whether to show it or not.

```
<li ng-if="@Model.punkt1.ToString().Length > 0">@Model.punkt1</li>
```

@Model.punkt1 returns a JValue, which i then convert to a string to check the length. This is for a grid editor in Umbraco, razor syntax is used. My scope merely contains the strings:

```
$scope.control.punkt1;
```

But I am getting this error when i run the page:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at ASP._Page_app_plugins_mygrideditor_infobox_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\thomb\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\LoevbjergRema1000Umbraco\LoevbjergRema1000Umbraco\LoevbjergRema1000Umbraco\App_Plugins\MyGridEditor\infobox.cshtml:line 8
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at Umbraco.Core.Profiling.ProfilingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Partials_grid_editors_base_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\thomb\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\LoevbjergRema1000Umbraco\LoevbjergRema1000Umbraco\LoevbjergRema1000Umbraco\Views\Partials\Grid\Editors\Base.cshtml:line 19
```

Why am i not able to check the length of my string?

EDIT:

```
<li ng-show="@Model.punkt1 != null &&  @Model.punkt1.ToString().Length > 0">@Model.punkt1</li>
                <li ng-show="@Model.punkt2 != null &&  @Model.punkt2.ToString().Length > 0">@Model.punkt2</li>
                <li ng-show="@Model.punkt3 != null &&  @Model.punkt3.ToString().Length > 0">@Model.punkt3</li>
                <li ng-show="@Model.punkt4 != null &&  @Model.punkt4.ToString().Length > 0">@Model.punkt4</li>
                <li ng-show="@Model.punkt5 != null &&  @Model.punkt5.ToString().Length > 0">@Model.punkt5</li>
```

And my angular controller:

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("my.custom.grideditorcontroller", function ($scope) {
    $scope.control.heading;

    $scope.control.punkt1 = "";
    $scope.control.punkt2 = "";
    $scope.control.punkt3 = "";
    $scope.control.punkt4 = "";
    $scope.control.punkt5 = "";
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference - Empty Excel Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235162/cannot-perform-runtime-binding-on-a-null-reference-empty-excel-cells)

Comment: so, you're getting a javscript variable name in the model?

Comment: I am getting a response back in JSON that has these properties: http://i.imgur.com/BT8KN8E.png ,  where "value" is my "punkt1" variable.

Comment: what is the datatype of `punkt1`

Comment: As I understand it, it is a JValue datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Check the null condition before convert the value to `string;`

Try this

```
<li ng-if="@Model.punkt1 != NULL &&  @Model.punkt1.ToString().Length > 0">@Model.punkt1</li>
```

for more details : [Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference - Empty Excel Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235162/cannot-perform-runtime-binding-on-a-null-reference-empty-excel-cells)

and kindly go with `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`. you can see the difference : [what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)

### EDIT:

You can't use `Convert.Tostring();` because of you are trying to get the length of string. So if the values is null , then the same error will threw. You should refer this  link for  [Difference between Convert.ToString() and .ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828154/difference-between-convert-tostring-and-tostring). So here you should check a `null` condition before getting the `length` of value which I mentioned above.

Comment: I am getting a different error now.I have included it as an edit.

Comment: I tried the solution you linked, but no reference for "Convert" was found. I will try using ng-show instead.

Comment: Thanks, i have made an edit with my current code, but  am still getting a null reference error.